# Cannot invoke '_' with an argument list of type '_' - Which of the two choices should I use?

Tags: swift

I have this error. I think I have two choices. Which one is best for my code? What do the differences mean?

> cannot invoke 'RGBtoHSV' with an argument list of type '(Float,Float,Float)'

`RGBtoHSV(CGFloat(r), CGFloat(g), CGFloat(b))`

`RGBtoHSV(CGFloat(), CGFloat(), CGFloat())`

Also if you take a look at the screen shot if you could give me some pointers regarding the other couple of errors that would be great too. I  know I have to match the types but I don't know the syntax order. http://i.imgur.com/sAckG6h.png

Thanks

```
func RGBtoHSV(r : CGFloat, g : CGFloat, b : CGFloat) -> (h : CGFloat, s : CGFloat, v : CGFloat) {
        var h : CGFloat = 0.0
        var s : CGFloat = 0.0
        var v : CGFloat = 0.0
        let col = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
        col.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &v, alpha: nil)
        return (h, s, v)
    }



// process the frame of video
    func captureOutput(captureOutput:AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer, fromConnection connection:AVCaptureConnection) {
        // if we're paused don't do anything
        if currentState == CurrentState.statePaused {
            // reset our frame counter
            self.validFrameCounter = 0
            return
        }

    // this is the image buffer
    var cvimgRef:CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    // Lock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cvimgRef, 0)
    // access the data
    var width: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvimgRef)
    var height:size_t = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvimgRef)
    // get the raw image bytes
    let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvimgRef))
    var bprow: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cvimgRef)


        var r:Float = 0.0
        var g:Float = 0.0
        var b:Float = 0.0

        for var y = 0; y < height; y++ {
            for var x:UInt8 = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {  // error: '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt8' and 'Int'
                b += buf[x]
                g += buf[x + 1]
                r += buf[x + 2]
            }
            buf += bprow(UnsafeMutablePointer(UInt8))  // error: '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' and 'size_t'
        }
        r /= 255 * (width*height)
        g /= 255 * (width*height)
        b /= 255 * (width*height)


    //} 



    // convert from rgb to hsv colourspace
        var h:Float = 0.0
        var s:Float = 0.0
        var v:Float = 0.0

    RGBtoHSV(r, g, b)  // error
```

Comment: for var x = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {
    b += buf[UInt8(x)]
    g += buf[UInt8(x+1)]
    r += buf[UInt8(x+2)]
}

Comment: If you are not sure which one of the `RGBtoHSV(...)` calls is the correct one, then why don't you try it? Write a small test app and use println() or the debugger to check what is calculated in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of type mismatch error.

The type of `x` should not be `UInt8` because `x` to increase until the value of the width.

```
for var x:UInt8 = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {  // error: '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt8' and 'Int'
```

So fix it like below:

```
for var x = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {
```

To increment the pointer address, you can use `advancedBy()` function.

```
buf += bprow(UnsafeMutablePointer(UInt8))  // error: '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' and 'size_t'
```

Like below:

```
var pixel = buf.advancedBy(y * bprow)
```

And this line,

```
RGBtoHSV(r, g, b)  // error
```

There are no implicit casts in Swift between `CGFloat` and `Float` unfortunately. So you should cast explicitly to `CGFloat`.

```
RGBtoHSV(CGFloat(r), g: CGFloat(g), b: CGFloat(b))
```

The whole edited code is here:

```
func RGBtoHSV(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) -> (h: CGFloat, s: CGFloat, v: CGFloat) {
    var h: CGFloat = 0.0
    var s: CGFloat = 0.0
    var v: CGFloat = 0.0
    let col = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
    col.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &v, alpha: nil)
    return (h, s, v)
}

// process the frame of video
func captureOutput(captureOutput:AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer, fromConnection connection:AVCaptureConnection) {
    // if we're paused don't do anything
    if currentState == CurrentState.statePaused {
        // reset our frame counter
        self.validFrameCounter = 0
        return
    }

    // this is the image buffer
    var cvimgRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    // Lock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cvimgRef, 0)
    // access the data
    var width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvimgRef)
    var height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvimgRef)
    // get the raw image bytes
    let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvimgRef))
    var bprow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cvimgRef)

    var r: Float = 0.0
    var g: Float = 0.0
    var b: Float = 0.0

    for var y = 0; y < height; y++ {
        var pixel = buf.advancedBy(y * bprow)
        for var x = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {  // error: '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt8' and 'Int'
            b += Float(pixel[x])
            g += Float(pixel[x + 1])
            r += Float(pixel[x + 2])
        }
    }
    r /= 255 * Float(width * height)
    g /= 255 * Float(width * height)
    b /= 255 * Float(width * height)

    //}

    // convert from rgb to hsv colourspace
    var h: Float = 0.0
    var s: Float = 0.0
    var v: Float = 0.0

    RGBtoHSV(CGFloat(r), g: CGFloat(g), b: CGFloat(b))  // error
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to change your function call to this `RGBtoHSV(CGFloat(r), CGFloat(g), CGFloat(b))` because I was getting an Xcode Fixit error.